# laravel specify the routes for every role

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to set up routing for different roles in my application but I am encountering an error. I want to know if the approach I am using is correct. I would like to specify the routes for each role and I am unsure if my method is the right one to achieve this.

This is my web.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


//guest pages
Route::get('/', function () {
  return redirect()->route('login');
});

Auth::routes();

route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
  Route::middleware('hasRole:Super Admin')->prefix('SuperAdmin')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('users')->group(function () {
      //users routes
      Route::get('', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
      Route::get('profile/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'show'])->name('profile.show');
      Route::put('profile/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
      Route::delete('/delete_user/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('users.destroy');
      Route::get('ajouter_utilisateur', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'create'])->name('user.create');
      Route::post('ajouter_utilisateur', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');
    });
    Route::prefix('fournisseurs')->name('fournisseur.')->group(function () {
      //fournisseurs routes
      Route::get('', [App\Http\Controllers\FournisseurController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
      Route::delete('{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FournisseurController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
      Route::get('edit_fournisseur/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\FournisseurController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
      Route::put('fournisseurs/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\FournisseurController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
      Route::get('ajouter_fournisseur', [App\Http\Controllers\FournisseurController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
      Route::post('ajouter_fournisseur', [App\Http\Controllers\FournisseurController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    });
    Route::prefix('factures')->name('facture.')->group(function () {
      //factures routes
      Route::get('', [App\Http\Controllers\FactureController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
      Route::delete('{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FactureController::class, 'destroy'])->name('destroy');
      Route::get('ajouter_facture', [App\Http\Controllers\FactureController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
      Route::post('ajouter_facture', [App\Http\Controllers\FactureController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
      Route::get('download/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FactureController::class, 'downloadFacture'])->name('downloadFacture');
    });
  });

  Route::middleware('hasRole:Admin')->prefix('Admin')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('users')->group(function () {
      //users routes
      Route::get('', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users.index');
      Route::get('profile/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'show'])->name('profile.show');
      Route::put('profile/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
      Route::delete('/delete_user/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('users.destroy');
      Route::get('ajouter_utilisateur', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'create'])->name('user.create');
      Route::post('ajouter_utilisateur', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'store'])->name('user.store');
    });
    Route::prefix('fournisseurs')->name('fournisseur.')->group(function () {
      //fournisseurs routes
      Route::get('', [App\Http\Controllers\FournisseurController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    });
    Route::prefix('factures')->name('facture.')->group(function () {
      //factures routes
      Route::get('', [App\Http\Controllers\FactureController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
      Route::get('download/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\FactureController::class, 'downloadFacture'])->name('downloadFacture');
    });
  });
});
```

And with this solution i get the error message

> Optimization failed (See output console for more details)

Can someone help me to find out the solution for this issue or suggest me the right way to do it?

Comment: What does the complete error ?

Comment: Also it is good if you refactor it to `Route::resource()`

Comment: i solved the error by adding a name for the second role groupe but in this case i need to call the route by the name of the role every time and this is not what i want, i need to call the route and the route is loaded if the user is authorized.

Answer (score 0):

for role management in Laravel I suggest you use "spatie/Laravel-permission".
this is documention link:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction
after install this package you must create middleware for each role and then check those on web.php